# Firebase cloud messaging in Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase-cloud-messaging

The following error is occurring on allowing permission in angular2 app. I am using the latest version of angular cli.

```
  The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
https://epush.in/firebase-messaging-sw.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
main.b757377….bundle.js:30496 permission An error occurred while retrieving token.  V {code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration", message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default s…). (messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration).", browserErrorMessage: "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').", stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to registe…in/main.b7573773d12a16423658.bundle.js:1572:3907)"}
```

Comment: Problem has been solved now. The problem was that In production mode 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file is not going to dist folder. You have to put your 'firebase-messaging-sw.js' file in your dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you load "/firebase-messaging-sw.js" in your browser, do you see a JavaScript file or something else? Sounds like that URL might be returning a HTML page (perhaps a 404 error)?